# Magento: How to display a custom date attribute in product listing?

Tags: magento, attributes, frontend, magento-1.5

I need to display a custom date attribute in product view and product listing. Currently, I am using the following code:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_date')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

For the product view this code works fine, but in product listing it does not.

The attribute option 'Used in Product Listing' is set to 'yes', but this does not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be doable with `$_product->getMyDate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to change the attributes scope from 'website' to 'store view' to got it working.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily get attribute value in listing page .

***but remember The attribute option 'Used in Product Listing' is set to 'yes'*** and try to run **reindex** it will solve your problem

just write

```
echo  $_product->getData('my_date')
```